# Wi-fi doesn't work on my iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, sim

If I do not have a SIM Card installed in my iPhone 4, will it still connect to the internet?

I have tried to connect via WiFi, it says that it is loading, yet doesn't connect.
I don't know if it has anything to do with the SIM Card because every time I try, it does not work and the message 'NO SIM CARD' shows up.

Answer (score 1):

**Absolutely.** I personally still own an iPhone 4 and am using it to access the internet without the SIM card installed. The notification bar shows *No Sim*, which but this does not impact the device's WiFi.

**The Common Fix: Resetting Network Settings**
I would like you to try: <kbd>Settings</kbd> > <kbd>General</kbd> > <kbd>Reset</kbd> > <kbd>Reset Network Settings</kbd>

Which should clear up any issues by resettings the Network gear to their default settings. It has shown to be a common [solution](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1777101) in the past. You will need to reconnect to your WiFi access point once the iPhone has restarted. Please report back with the status afterward.